No value causes: The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type
This is a runtime error.
Future<int> nuclearPlant() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  throw "up";
  return 999999999;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final zillionVolts = await nuclearPlant().catchError((e) {
    // Someone forgot to return 0 here.
    // oops, the nuclear plant will overheat and explode
  });
  print(zillionVolts);
  coolDownPlant();
}

void coolDownPlant() {
  print("Done, safely shutdown the plant.");
}


Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError
must return a value of the future's type

How make Dart analysis options raise error on this before ?
invalid_return_type_for_catch_error: error

Doesn't help

Again, if you avoid using catchError entirely then you would avoid this problem.

Try catch is nice but the extra indent is really annoying. Anyways, I found an even better solution, I extended Future with an extension method called beforeError , takes a callback. And used try catch on the await this. I don't have to return a value

I found it
body_might_complete_normally_catch_error: error

